# How can I add two labels together which one has a "$" in front of the text?

Tags: c#

I have a Dictionary that holds various string including string numbers with a dollar sign. I am trying to add two labels together but obviously a "$" wont parse. I am using a try and catch:

```
        try
        {
            int total = 0;
            total = int.Parse(priceLabel.Text) + int.Parse(totalLabel.Text);
            totalLabel.Text = total.ToString();
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
```

I am not sure how to get it to work, the priceLabel is the one that has the "$" attacthed.

Comment: exactly the same question as yesterday.

Comment: i looked for questions like this and didn't see any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution would be to replace the `$` with empty character:

```
total = int.Parse(priceLabel.Text.Replace("$", "")) + int.Parse(totalLabel.Text);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, Works great.

Comment: I did all of that, just had to wait 5 minutes to accept answer.

Answer (score 2):

You mention a dictionary, but your example only shows labels, so let's just deal with labels as an example (the concept is the same no matter what the source of the string value).

The `decimal` type actually has a way to deal with currency symbols. You could use the following code to get a numeric value from your string. Then the decimal can be cast to an int at the end if that's the type you want to deal with (i.e. if there's no decimal in the currency amount):

```
int total = (int)(decimal.Parse(priceLabel.Text, NumberStyles.Currency) + 
    decimal.Parse(totalLabel.Text, NumberStyles.Currency));

totalLabel.Text = total.ToString();
```